# Error when triing to use a Custom Robo injector

Tags: android, roboguice

I'm trying to use RobuGuice for my Sony SmallApplication, I tried creating a RoboSmallApplication(here is the code - https://gist.github.com/abyu/6447828) as done in RoboActivity. But When I do that and try to run my application on Android I get the following error,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.skk.texting.MainActivity: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
    1) null returned by binding at roboguice.config.DefaultRoboModule.configure(DefaultRoboModule.java:138)
    but roboguice.inject.ContentViewListener.activity is not @Nullable
    while locating roboguice.inject.NullProvider<android.app.Activity>
    at roboguice.config.DefaultRoboModule.configure(DefaultRoboModule.java:138)
    while locating android.app.Activity
    for field at roboguice.inject.ContentViewListener.activity(Unknown Source)
    at roboguice.inject.ContentViewListener.class(Unknown Source)
    while locating roboguice.inject.ContentViewListener
    for field at com.skk.texting.RoboSmallApplication.ignored(Unknown Source)
    while locating com.skk.texting.MainActivity
```

can some one help me fix this issue. Thanks

Comment: found a fix. Removing inject of ContentViewListener has fixed it. Code at https://gist.github.com/abyu/6447828